# What does the number 25699 mean on my surfboard dimensions?

Tags: surfing

I have a surfboard that has the following dimensions written on it:
6'8" 18 3/4" 25699

[image]

What does the number 25699 mean? I've always seen the third number either be the thickness in inches, or the volume in litres.

Comment: It might be the serial number, given that it looks hand-signed.

Comment: It might also be a date, 25th of June 1999.